# Dynamically calling a function on a contract

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call different functions of a contract with a single function that has the function name passed to it as an argument.

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io'));
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(data.abi), data.address);

var method = data.method // 'getWord'
myContract.methods.getWord().call().then(function(value) {
        console.log(value)
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

Above I have created a variable called method and its value has been set to `getWord` on the line below I am calling `getWord()`

What I'm trying to do is call whatever function is named in data.method like this...

```
    myContract.methods.[data.method].call().then(function(value) {
        console.log(value)
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

but of course it breaks and id prefer to not use `eval()` like this

```
    var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(data.abi), data.address);
    eval('myContract.methods.'+data.method+'().call()')  
    .then(function(value) {
        console.log(value)
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should just be:

```
myContract.methods[data.method]().call()
```

(You had an extra dot in there.)

Comment: I tried without the dot and got `TypeError: myContract.methods[data.method].call(...).then is not a function`

Comment: Sorry, see my edit. I forgot to actually call the function. :-)